# What data type are JavaScript object references and what is the most efficient way to store them?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory-management, reference

Let's say we have this object: `var a = {x: 3}`.

Now, if we have an array `arr = [a]` that holds a reference to this object, what `arr[0]` actually stores is a reference to that object, not the actual object data.

I have many objects (20k+) such as `a` that I want to keep track of, probably creating an array similar to `arr` each second. As I want the memory allocation to be as efficient as possible, can I somehow tell the compiler that my array will only contain references to objects like `a`? I thought of using something like `TypedArray`, but I don't know what type the reference of `a` is, I guess I can't just use `new UInt32Array()` and actually store `a` at each index.

In languages like C++ you could have an array of pointers and you always know the size of a pointer (eg: 8 bytes on 64bit machines).

Is there any way to efficiently store references/pointers to objects in an `Array` or `Object`?

Comment: and what is the problem behind?

Comment: Doing    `var a = {x:123,y:345};  var b = [a];`  is like creating a pointer.. In fact after adding a to b, if you change a.  the b[0] will have the change.  But one advantage compared to C++, you don't need to worry about cleaning up afterwards.. :)

Comment: @NinaScholz I want to create an array of 20k elements each second (actually much faster than that). In something like C++ if you know the number of elements and type of each element you can malloc the memory that you need. I ask if there is something simillar in JavaScript where when you know the size of the Array and what each element will be you can just directly allocate the memory (actually signal the compiler that you might need that memory), without multiple memory allocations happen while you add the references in the array.

Comment: There is `var b = Array(20000)`

Comment: References doesn't take a lot of space, probably take as much as pointers take in other languages (or even less depending on how JS engines optimize that).

Comment: @Keith I know, but that doesn't tell the compiler anything about the data type stored in the array. Is it by default "ready" to store references? For example new Int32Array(20000) will allocate 20000 * 4 bytes of memory. How much memory does `Array(20000)` allocate?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir It's not about how much memory they take, I know it's not much, it's about creating the initial `Array` exactly the right size, so when the elements are added into the `Array` no new memory has to be allocated.

Comment: Coming from C++ / Delphi / C#, etc.  What I would suggest is your don't overthink this yet!..   I know it kind of feels wrong, but trust me, when it comes to performance, the Javascript Engines have some pretty neat tricks up there sleeve's, so you don't have to worry about it.  And in fact if you try and over-optimise now, you might find it actually hits performance, rather than helps..

Comment: @Cristy Well javascript doesn't provide type-to-type conversion. So even if you find out that a refernce is exactly UInt32 in size, you won't be able to convert a UInt32 to a reference.

Comment: To give you an example of what I mean, performance wise. your example of allocating 20,000 objects, and placing into an array on my machine took less than 5ms.

Comment: @Keith Yeah, but I do that at 60FPS, so I have less than 16ms to create the array + do other computations, this is why I need it to be as efficient as possible. I know that this is a lot and not recommended, but for now this is what I need.

Comment: Hmm, I just thought of this: what if I first create an array of 20k references, then when I want a new one, I copy this one and update the elements. I guess this way the array will be the correct size when copied.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers my own questions. I can create an initial Array, add the elements that I want to it and then whenever I need a new array, just copy this one and update the elements. This way it doesn't matter what data type are the references, as I can directly allocate exactly the entire memory needed for the array.

Example in a pseudo-JavaScript:

```
var initialArray = [];
// push initial references into this array
// whenever I need a new array do:
var newArray = initialArray.slice();
// update references in the newArray
...
for i in newArray
newArray[i] = newRefi;
...
```

This way the `newArray` will be the correct size when created.

**LE:** Although this works in theory, it actually makes performance worse, probably because now creating the `newArray` now has to copy memory and do other crazy stuff instead of just allocating some memory.

Comment: @Keith Can you elaborate?

Comment: You assuming the memory allocated is going to get reserved, and as you put the object back in the memory allocated would not shift, so your assuming it will help performance..  Just doing a quick test here, performance wise, just pushing back into the original array with new object, or doing an Array(20000); again are both faster than the slice method.

Comment: To, add..  In all cases the V8 engine in Chrome, was very clever.  In that it detected memory allocation patterns, and optimises them for future references anyway.  So it's doing what your after anyway..  That was the part about how Javascript Engines have some clever tricks up there sleeves, and if you try an optimise, you might be wasting your time.  Like I said coming from C++/Delphi etc, I know how you feel.  But it really is a different world in the Javascript land and JIT compiling..

Comment: @Keith Yes, you are right, JavaScript is very strange when it comes to performance. Sometimes trying to make things faster actually makes them slower. So yeah, I should probably go the easy way and just let the compiler do all those things.

Comment: `So yeah, I should probably go the easy way and just let the compiler do all those things`   Yeah, certainly to start with, and when you find a performance problem, then look at it in more detail.   The Debuggers built into say Chrome / Firefox nowadays have some really good performance monitoring tools, way better than you would find in say C++, C# etc.